# how to promisify the mongoDB with the util's promisify function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, es6-promise

I want to use the promisify with the MongoDB. I try the code at last, the connect is OK, but the function insertOne not. Could anyone help me out? And it is better to explain why, and what is a context when with '.db().collection()', how should I make the function promisify with the code like:

```
a().b().c().d()
```

and here is my code like bellow.

```
import "babel-polyfill"
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const util = require('util')
const chalk = require('chalk')

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
const dbName = ''
const collName = ''

let connect = util.promisify(mongoClient.connect).bind(mongoClient)
let insertOne = util.promisify(mongoClient.insertOne)
                .bind(mongoClient)

const main = async () => {
    try {
        await connect(url)
        insertOne({a100: 1}).db(dbName).collection(collName)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(chalk.red(err.toString()))
    }

    mongoClient.close()
}    

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

The MongoDB driver already returns promises (see the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect)). You don't need to use `util.promisify`. Also, you don't chain `db` and `collection` on queries like `insertOne`. It's the other way round.

For example:

```
 client = await mongoClient.connect(url)
 client.db(dbName).collection(collName).insertOne({a100: 1})
```

(NB if you're using the old mongodb node driver version 2.2 it's slightly different as connect returns a db object - [documentation for 2.2](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoClient.html#.connect))